# Why do Hindus cover their head?

Tags: temple, worship, culture, women

All Hindu women cover their heads in Temples and during prayers which shows respect towards God. [Here](http://www.boldsky.com/yoga-spirituality/faith-mysticism/2014/why-indian-women-cover-their-head-047138.html) I have found *there is no mention of women covering their head in any of the Hindu texts.* **If it is not mentioned any where then how we came to know about this?** Also in other religions Males cover their heads as well, So does it exist in our culture also?

Comment: My understanding is covering head is a sign of respect.

Comment: Isn't this mainly North Indian tradition?  I think this is cultural not religious.

Comment: @Aks Are you sure it is Cultural?

Comment: @Ketan Yes, it is.

Comment: This is a regional and caste-based practice. South Indian women do not cover their heads in general. Kshatriya women do at times.

Comment: Seems to be Islamic influence.

Comment: refer -Rig Veda Book no. 8 Hymn no. 33 V. no. 19 >19 Cast down thine eyes and look not up. More closely set thy feet. Let none
See what thy garment veils, for thou, a Brahman, hast become a dame.

Answer (score 2):

> Visitors and worshipers to Hindu temples are required to remove shoes
>   and other footwear before entering. Additionally, it may be customary,
>   particularly at South Indian temples, for men to remove shirts and to
>   cover pants and shorts with a traditional cloth known as a vasthiram
>
> Most rituals in North Indian temples are very simple in stark contrast
>   to South Indian temples, which have elaborate practices. For example,
>   a strict dress code exists for people who wish to enter the Guruvayur
>   Temple. Men are to wear around their waist, without any dress covering
>   their chest. Girls and women are not allowed to wear any trouser-like
>   dresses or short skirts. They are allowed to wear a sari, and girls
>   are to wear long skirts and blouses. Presently the dress code for
>   women has been relaxed, and salwar kameezes or churidar pyjamas are
>   being allowed.
>
> North Indian temples often tend to be less orthodox. Like all other
>   temples in India, footwear is strictly prohibited. Unlike in northern
>   India, in Kerala and other southern Indian states, Hindu women do not
>   cover their heads in temples. In traditional north Indian homes, women
>   still cover their head in front of in-laws and elders as a sign of
>   appreciation and respect. Thus, covering the hair in temples is mostly
>   a north Indian custom and is not mandatory. It is an outward sign of
>   displaying feelings of deep respect, humility and gratitude towards
>   the Divine.

[Source](http://www.sanskritimagazine.com/rituals_and_practices/why-women-cover-their-head-in-sacred-places/)

Comment: Thanks for the answer and your source. But I was expecting something like _The Head cover for Muslim women is specifically mentioned in Quran(24:31)_ (seen in the source you have cited), from our Scriptures.